# how to get json data and print Dictionary of Array Integer value into my tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

haiii i have json data like

```
{
NetworkMembers =         (
                {
        id = 1;
        memberId = 1;
        networkId = 1;
        position = 0;
        type = H;
    },
```

and finally I put into array like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) { 
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i]; 
    NSArray *array2=[dictionary valueForKey:@"NetworkMembers"]; 
    for (int j=0; j<[array2 count]; j++) { 
        NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:j]; 
        NSLog(@"J value %@",[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"type"]); 
        [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2valueForKey:@"type"]]; 
        [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"id"]]; 
    } 
}
```

finally I get like 
tableArray (
    H,
    1,
    H,
    2,
    H,
    3,
    H,
    4,
    H,
    6
then in cell for row at index path i wrote code like

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testing"];


if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"testing"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [tablArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([tablArray count]>0)
{
           cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[tablArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringValue];
}

return cell;
```

but printing detail text lable iam getting error like
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109314510'
*** First throw call stack:
 Thank in advance can any one help me

Comment: i put ony type and id in array iam getting type in table cell but onely problm with detail text labl

Comment: Your array doesnt contains nsstring whereas I think it contains NetworkMembers . So , you have to typecast during fetch or insertion of array

Comment: First print your `tableArray` in console howz it look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be better to get a NSArray of dictionary with a key for the type and a key for the id and so `tableArray` will be :

```
// Create a property of tableArray to retrieve data later
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableArray

// Add data inside your tableArray your viewDidLoad
NSDictionary *dicAllNetworks = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]; // Retrieve data from your JSON file inside a NSDictionary

_tableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dic in [dicAllNetworks objectForKey:@"NetworkMembers"])
{
    [tableArray addObject:@{@"id" : [dic objectForKey:@"id"], @"type": [dic objectForKey:@"type"]}];
}
NSLog(@"%@", tableArray);
```

And you will get your array like this :

```
tableArray (
        {
        id = 1;
        type = H;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        type = H;
    }
)
```

and next modify your code like this :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[tablArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"type"];
if([tablArray count]>0)
{
           cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[tablArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

Comment: add your code when you received your JSON and I will show you how to get the array of dictionary

Comment: tableArray (
    H,
    1,
    H,
    2,
    H,
    3,
    H,
    4,
    H,
    6
)
iam only taking type and id

Comment: yes but here you can't use correctly this array because you don't know which id is with the type. Trust me, dictionary will be better for you

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109542850'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: its going to crash iam getting same message

Comment: Of course ^^ You need to get an array of dictionary ! Edit your answer and add your code when you get your JSON into your array please

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {        NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *array2=[dictionary valueForKey:@"NetworkMembers"];
                for (int j=0; j<[array2 count]; j++)
        {            NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:j];
            NSLog(@"J value %@",[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"type"]);
            
            [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2valueForKey:@"type"]];
            [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"id"]];
           
        }
        
    
        
    }

Comment: iam adding to array like this in didReceiveData

Comment: (
        {
        NetworkMembers =         (
                        {
                id = 1;
                memberId = 1;
                networkId = 1;
                position = 0;
                type = H;
            },

Comment: on your for loop, what is `array` ? Add the code where you get data for this NSArray

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *array2=[dictionary valueForKey:@"NetworkMembers"];
        
        for (int j=0; j<[array2 count]; j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:j];
            NSLog(@"J value %@",[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"type"]);
            
            [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"type"]];
            [self.tablArray addObject:[dictionary2 valueForKey:@"id"]];
           
        }

Comment: ^^ how do you get `array` in `for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)`

Comment: Array is my main array and table array is which is existed in dictionary of array

Comment: iam going to put whole data into array first like                        self.array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

Comment: so use my code and change this self.array by `NSDictionary *dicAllNetworks = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];`